# How to use the webcam to take a picture and convert it into an image file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm working on making a facial recognition system, and I'm using the API called Kairos. It allows me to upload an image and detect if there's a face or not. But I want to create a button event that allows me to use a webcam to take a picture live and detect it. What should I do?

```html
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="form-post.php"> 
    <input type="file" id="imageFile" name="file"><button type="button" id="testDetect">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
$("#testDetect").click(function () {
    var file = $('#imageFile')[0].files[0]; 
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      var imageData = parseImageData(reader.result);
      var data = {};
      data.image = imageData;
      $.ajax({
     url      : "http://localhost/Karios/simple-detect/form-post.php",
     type     : "POST",
     data     :  data,
     dataType : 'text'
   }).done(function(response) {
      
     console.log(response)
     if(response === true){
    alert('fail!');
  }
  else{
    alert('successs!');
   }
   })
    }
});
```

Comment: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm take a look at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on  [TAKE jpg webcam PHOTO with HTML5](http://fuel-efficient-vehicles.org/pwsdb/?p=304) with some modifications because the script is old.

1 - Create a folder named `images` to store the files
2 - Create a file named `html5-webcam-save.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
$rawData = $_POST['imgBase64'];
print $rawData;
$filteredData = explode(',', $rawData);
$unencoded = base64_decode($filteredData[1]);
$datime = date("Y-m-d-H.i.s", time() ) ; # - 3600*7
$userid  = $_POST['userid'] ;
// name & save the image file
$fp = fopen('images/'.$datime.'-'.$userid.'.jpg', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $unencoded);
fclose($fp);
```

3 - Create the main page:

**selfie_html5.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
<script>
    navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia );
    if (navigator.getUserMedia)
    {
        navigator.getUserMedia(
            {
                video:true,
                audio:false
            },
            function(stream) { /* do-say something */ },
            function(error) { alert('Something went wrong. (error code ' + error.code + ')');
                return; }
        );
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry, the browser you are using doesn't support the HTML5 webcam API");
    }
</script>
    <style>
        .camcontent{
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 480px;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .cambuttons button {
            border-radius: 15px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        .cambuttons button:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 15px;
            background: #00dd00 ;    /* green */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Put event listeners into place
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            video = document.getElementById("video"),
            videoObj = { "video": true },
            image_format= "jpeg",
            jpeg_quality= 85,
            errBack = function(error) {
                console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
            };


        // Put video listeners into place
        if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
            navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                //video.src = stream;
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();
                $("#snap").show();
            }, errBack);
        } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
                $("#snap").show();
            }, errBack);
        } else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // moz-prefixed
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
                $("#snap").show();
            }, errBack);
        }
        // video.play();       these 2 lines must be repeated above 3 times
        // $("#snap").show();  rather than here once, to keep "capture" hidden
        //                     until after the webcam has been activated.

        // Get-Save Snapshot - image
        document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
            // the fade only works on firefox?
            $("#video").fadeOut("slow");
            $("#canvas").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#snap").hide();
            $("#reset").show();
            $("#upload").show();
        });
        // reset - clear - to Capture New Photo
        document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function() {
            $("#video").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#canvas").fadeOut("slow");
            $("#snap").show();
            $("#reset").hide();
            $("#upload").hide();
        });
        // Upload image to sever
        document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.85);
            $("#uploading").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "html5-webcam-save.php",
                data: {
                    imgBase64: dataUrl,
                    user: "Joe",
                userid: 25
        }
        }).done(function(msg) {
                console.log("saved");
                $("#uploading").hide();
                $("#uploaded").show();
            });
        });
    }, false);

</script>


<div class="camcontent">
    <video id="video" autoplay></video>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"> </canvas>
</div>
<div class="cambuttons">
    <button id="snap" style="display:none;">  Capture </button>
    <button id="reset" style="display:none;">  Reset  </button>
    <button id="upload" style="display:none;"> Upload </button>
    <br> <span id=uploading style="display:none;"> Uploading has begun . . .  </span>
    <span id=uploaded  style="display:none;"> Success, your photo has been uploaded!</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Notes:

I've tested the code and it works as expected. If you run into problems, make sure you have write permissions on `images` folder.

**Folder structur**e:

```
/
  html5-webcam-save.php
  selfie_html5.html
  /images (folder)
```

Comment: The webcam works pretty well, thanks! I just have a few more questions.   
1. how to put the webcam into a button event?                                                      2.After taking the picture, where the picture goes? I can't find it in images folder.                                                                                                                                          3.How to make a change base on the ajax above? Use the taken pictures instead of uploading the images.                                   Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, I've updated the answer with a folder structure.

Comment: Thanks for helping! So I put those file in the same folder, but I still can't find the images. Also, you kinda skipped my question 1 and 3. Could you please help me? I'm new to programming :)

Comment: Please  open a new question and post the link here, I'll try to help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44017038/how-to-capture-the-webcam-picture-and-convert-it-into-jpg-file-and-later-execut

Comment: Pedro Lobito please go to my new page and help, thanks!

Comment: I'll take a look